# .Bak file parsing using method replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex

I want to omit out some details from my sample file. I don't want the "[SID: 20068] SMB Request BO detected.  Traffic has been blocked from this application: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntoskrnl.exe," to appear in the parsed file after I have written the file output. I have omitted the rest of the file details due to privacy and security issues. I tried to use the "\" because I thought it was linked to special characters of regex function but it doesn't seem to work, meaning that it is still not omitted out from the output file.

Sample file:

```
20:02:15 SymantecServer CALVIN: teller,[SID: 20068] SMB Request BO detected.  Traffic has been blocked from this application: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
19:58:40 Occurrences: 1,Application: C:/WINDOWS/system32/ntoskrnl.exe,Location: Home - LAN,User: Administrator,Domain: HUMBLE
```

Expected output:

```
20:02:15 SymantecServer CALVIN: teller,(....other file details which are omitted due to privacy)
19:58:40 Occurrences: 1,Application: C:/WINDOWS/system32/ntoskrnl.exe,Location: Home - LAN,User: Administrator,Domain: HUMBLE
```

My code:

```
try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = "", oldtext = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                oldtext += line + "\r\n";
            }
            reader.close();

            // replace a word in a file
            oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("\\[SID: 20068\\] SMB Request BO detected.  Traffic has been blocked from this application: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ntoskrnl.exe,Local: 192.168.28.88,", "");
            oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("\\[SID: 21545\\] SMB Guest Login detected.  Traffic has been allowed from this application: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ntoskrnl.exe,", "");
            oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("\\[SID: 23471\\] MS SMB2 Validate Provider Callback RCE detected.  Traffic has been blocked from this application: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ntoskrnl.exe,", "");
            oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("\\[SID: 23180\\] MSRPC Server Service Buffer Overflow 2 detected.  Traffic has been blocked from this application: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ntoskrnl.exe,", "");
            oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("\"Denial of Service \"\"Ping of Death\"\" attack detected. Description:  In a Ping of Death attack, the hacker uses a packet with a size that is larger than the normal standard. When your system encounters a packet of this size, it often crashes, hangs, or reboots.\",", "");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("new_bakky.bak");

            // the entire file is contained within the String 'oldtext'
            // you only need one write operation to output it
            writer.write(oldtext);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: From your code, you seem to be replacing literals and wouldn't really need regex for that (see `String#replace`). Note that no replacement query in your code example matches the input snippet.

Comment: Yes i did try without the regex but it didnt work for me too. still the same file as it was before :(